# Redirect from an App

Tags: android, redirect

How would I go about catching a user trying to use the Message application and either redirect them to my App or throw up a message?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  I don't think you can do this simply, but I wonder what would happen if your app's package and class names are exactly as those of the standard Messenger app.

Comment: You can't use the same package names, app will not install then.

Answer (score 1):

you register your app for the same Intent in the Manifest. Then user can chose if he would like to use your application to write messages or another one. E.g. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING

E.g. in your `AndroidManifest.xml` add to your Activity:

```
<activity .... >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MESSAGING" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But: you can't force users to use your app. If user decides that his messaging app should be default for that Intent then you have no way to intercept that.